# ionic 2/3 build fail

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I need help, I can not build my app, I get the following error:

```
[19:09:38]  typescript: src/pages/sidemenu/sidemenu.ts, line: 24 
[19:09:38]  typescript: src/pages/sidemenu/sidemenu.ts, line: 25 
[19:09:38]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[19:09:38]  Error: Failed to transpile program 
Error: Failed to transpile program
    at new BuildError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:137:20
    at Promise ()
    at transpileWorker (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:103:12)
    at Object.transpile (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:61:12)
    at buildProject (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:97:78)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:47:16
    at   

npm info lifecycle payman@0.0.1~build: Failed to exec build script
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! payman@0.0.1 build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the payman@0.0.1 build script.
This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

can anybody help me please??

Comment: Can you show us your `src/pages/sidemenu/sidemenu.ts` file?

Comment: Here it is: [sidemenu.ts](https://pastebin.com/pTCqXq1u)

Answer (score 0):

Happens most of the time because of the version of `@ionic/app-scripts` try to remove the package and add it again using `npm`

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! but I still have the same error. I removed @ionic/app-scripts and I added it again but I still get the same error when trying to build the app.

Comment: can you try creating a new app and moving your files there? I did that lately and worked

Comment: I did not try to do that, I'm going to try.